# how to filter nodes that match url of current node or particular field of current node

Tags: views, entities, uri

For my contenttype 'cars' i use a panel node-view.

Each 'car' node has fields 'categorie' and 'type'
Each 'car' node has url 'categorie/type/model' e.g.
'car/toyota/yaris'

In my 'car' panel node-view i like to insert a view.
This view should filter nodes  that match the field 'type' or part of the url 'type'

Without succes i have tried to pass the node id as an argument from my view (master) to my panel. Then using node id as a contextual filter.

Comment: are you asking how to create a view? any view?  a simple web search would yield perhaps hundreds of resources on how to build Views of all sorts

Comment: See my edits. 
I am familiar with creating views
and have googled on usecases similar to mine..

Comment: there's no use in giving a suggestion you've already tried, so what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed to create a working view:

Under contextual filter:
-Content: Has taxonomy term ID

Configured:

Provide default value - Type:

Taxonomy term from url - load default filter from term page (checked)

Specify validation criteria (checked)

Validator: taxonomy term (selected)

Check term in vocabulary list

Filter type: term name converted to term id (selected)